# Otimização em programação competitiva - C++ - Problema de TLE

Tags: c++, desempenho

Estou solucionando uma questão que pede para imprimirmos na tela o id do ganhador de cada rodada de teste.

O jogo funciona da seguinte forma:

São distribuídas N cartas para P jogadores de um total de G cartas.

A carta [G - N*P+1] será destinada ao descarte e as cartas seguintes irão para o saque(a ordem das cartas na entrada é a ordem do topo para a base do monte).

1. Jogo segue em sentido horário
2. há dois montes, um de descarte e o outro de saque.
3. Na rodada do jogador, caso ele possua uma carta com o valor ou naipe equivalente à carta do topo do descarte, ele poderá descartar a carta (caso varias cartas sejam candidatas, é descartada a de maior valor).
4. Caso o jogador não possua cartas candidatas ele terá de pegar uma carta do topo do saque.
5. ganha o jogador que descartar todas as cartas.

OBS: Algumas cartas tem poderes (estilo uno):

- carta 12(Dama): inverte a direção do jogo. Caso seja a primeira carta no começo do jogo (a carta que começa no descarte), o primeiro jogador P[0] jogará normalmente mas o próximo será o anti horário (P = 0,1,2,3; então anti horário = 0,3,2,1,0...)
- carta 7: o próximo jogador perde a vez e pega duas cartas do saque.
- carta 1: o próximo jogador perde a vez e pega uma carta do saque.
- carta 11: o próximo jogador perde a vez.

O texto original da questão esta em: https://neps.academy/problem/270

resolvi com o seguinte código:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define ff first
#define ss second
#define pb push_back
#define PLAYERS 10

const char PAUS = 'C';
const char OUROS = 'D';
const char COPAS = 'H';
const char ESPADAS = 'S';

using namespace std;
using ia = pair<int, char>;

ia descarte;
vector<ia> mao[PLAYERS];
vector<ia> saque;
int players, pcards, gcards;
bool effect = false, sentido = true;

void verifyEffect(){
    if(descarte.ff == 1 || descarte.ff == 7 || descarte.ff == 11)
        effect = true;
    else if(descarte.ff == 12){
        sentido = !sentido;
    }
}
bool vePlayer(ia a, ia b){
    if(a.ff == descarte.ff || b.ff == descarte.ff){
        if(a.ff == b.ff){
            if(a.ss == ESPADAS || (a.ss == COPAS && b.ss != ESPADAS) || (a.ss == OUROS && b.ss == PAUS))
                return false;
        }else if(a.ff == descarte.ff) return false;
    }
    if(a.ss == descarte.ss || b.ss == descarte.ss){
        if(a.ss == b.ss && a.ff > b.ff) return false;  
        else if(a.ss == descarte.ss) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int proxRound(int jogadorr = -1){ // jogador = atual != prox
    int jogador = jogadorr;
    int proxJogador;
    if(jogador == -1) jogador = 0;
    if(sentido){
        if(jogador+1 > players - 1) proxJogador = 0;
        else proxJogador = jogador + 1;
    }else{
        if(jogador-1 < 0) proxJogador = players - 1;
        else proxJogador = jogador - 1;
    }
    //printf("jogador: %d\n", jogador);
    if(effect){
        if(descarte.ff == 1){
            mao[jogador].pb(saque.back());
            saque.pop_back();
        }else if(descarte.ff == 7){
            mao[jogador].pb(saque.back());
            saque.pop_back();
            mao[jogador].pb(saque.back());
            saque.pop_back();
        }
        effect = false;  
    }else{
        sort(mao[jogador].begin(), mao[jogador].end(), vePlayer);
        if(mao[jogador].back().ss == descarte.ss || mao[jogador].back().ff == descarte.ff){
            descarte = mao[jogador].back();
            mao[jogador].pop_back();
            if(mao[jogador].size() == 0){
                return jogador + 1; 
            }
            verifyEffect();
        }else{
            mao[jogador].pb(saque.back());
            saque.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return proxRound(proxJogador);
}
int main(){

    while(true){
        //printf("entrou\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &players, &pcards, &gcards);
        effect = false;
        if(players == 0 && pcards == 0 && gcards == 0) break;
        for(int jogador = 0; jogador < players; jogador++){
            mao[jogador].clear();
            for(int cartas = 0; cartas < pcards; cartas++){
                pair<int,char> c;
                scanf("%d %c", &c.ff, &c.ss);
                mao[jogador].pb(c); // emplace_back(ff,ss)
            }
        }
        scanf("%d %c", &descarte.ff,&descarte.ss);
        verifyEffect();

        saque.clear();
        saque.reserve(gcards - players*pcards);
        for(int nsaque = gcards - players*pcards - 2; nsaque >= 0; nsaque--){
            pair<int,char> c;
            scanf("%d %c", &saque[nsaque].ff ,&saque[nsaque].ss);
        }
        printf("%d\n", proxRound());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ele retorna a resposta correta, porém recebo TLE (Tempo limite excedido).
Como posso otimizar esse código?

O tempo limite é de 1s.

Comment: O compilador deveria remover essa recursão de cauda, mas já tentou remover você mesmo e trocar por um laço em `proxRound`? De toda sorte, você consegue ver os "hotspots" usando o `kcachegrind`, uma ferramenta do `valgrind`. Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Usage.html) para tirar suas dúvidas. Claro, use redirecionamento de entrada para evitar computar seu tempo interagindo. Se estiver no Windows, tente uma ferramenta nativa, parece que o `valgrind` não funciona tão bem no WSL